# Mysql LOAD DATA IN FILE discard file like Oracle Sql Loader does

Tags: mysql, csv, load, load-data-infile

I have to load several CSVs into some tables with Mysql **LOAD DATA IN FILE,** and I want to save discard records that could not be loaded (Because failed FKs, duplicates, etc.) in a discard file, such as Oracle SQL loader does

Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Comment: Nothing like that in mysql. Either validate the data before load or load to staging table and validate that.

Comment: Impossible in single query (especially while taking into account that any error stops loading but the rows already loaded are not removed/rollbacked). Easy - in stored procedure. Load all data into intermediate table, then move rows one-by-one to working table. The rest will be non-loaded rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can import data easily using MySQL WorkBench using import wizard through CSV.  It has the option to import all the data and create new table. From there you can alter the tables later on or make necessary indexes as needed, or change dataTypes on the go.

Another option is to use LOAD DATA commands as usual. Import data to a newly created tables without the foreign keys. You can target csv columns to specific table columns as well. see  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html